# Why is $p$ a proof of $A$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, proof-theory, type-theory

How do I see that "the logical proposition $A$ in (3) can be proved by the term $p$ in (4)"? What does it even mean that the term $p$  proves $A$ ?

(Source of the screenshot: [https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/~zhaohui/LACompLing18post.pdf](https://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/%7Ezhaohui/LACompLing18post.pdf))

> [image]

Comment: Trying with a vague comment aimed at proivide some intuition... as per answer below, a *proposition* in the mathematical world is an "abstract" object, because when we consider a math theorem we are considering its content (not the written words used in the book...). Thus it is a *type* (consider also: Type vs Token) and its proof are the "elements" of the type, because we understand a theorem through its proof: this is the constructive part of modern Type Theory: no platonic essences but human made proofs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what the Curry-Howard principle is about: we **interpret** types as *propositions* and their elements as *proofs* of those propositions.
In our example, we have a type $A,$ and one can construct its element $p$ as given by the formula (4). Curry-Howard tells us: if $A$ is viewed as a proposition, $p$ is a proof of $A$.

In other words, "$x$ is an element of $X$" means under Curry-Howard correspondence the same as "$x$ is a proof of $X$" - these are just two ways to say one thing.

The idea is that a *type* $T$ is like a set of *ways* for the *proposition* $T$ to hold. Then, if there is some element $x:T$, then there is some *way* in which $T$ holds, so $T$ is proven by exhibiting $x$. E.g. in our case $A$ is the set of ways to construct for any $P, x$ an inclusion from $P(x)$ to $P(x)$; $p$ exhibits one such way: the trivial inclusion $\lambda y.y$. Note how a simpler example hides in this one: $P(x) \subset P(x)$ is a type/proposition. As a type, it is something like the type of inclusions, whereas as a proposition, it is a set of *witnesses* that $P(x) \subset P(x)$ is true. $\lambda y.y$ is one such witness.

Comment: Thanks, it made things intuitively more clear. But on a more formal level I'm still not sure if I completely get it. We have a purely syntactic object $\lambda P: Nat\to Prop \ \lambda x: Nat \ \lambda y: P(x).y$ that is supposed to be a proof of $A$. I assume there should be some formal procedure (like natural deduction rules or something) of establishing that this object is a proof of $A$? And in general, what is a proof, to begin with? Why does a proof of $A$ have to have the form in (4) (e.g. why does it have to start with $\lambda P: Nat\to Prop$)?

Comment: A proof _is_ an element of $A$! We call any element of $A$ a proof. So the procedure consists only in ensuring that the expression for $p$ is well-typed.

Comment: $p$ starts as $\lambda P ...$ because this is how elements of $A$ look: they are functions from the type of $P$'s. Since proofs of $A$ = elements of $A$, we expect a proof to look like this.

Comment: Then I guess I don't fully understand what the elements of $A$ look like. $A$ expresses the fact that for all objects $P$ of type $Nat\to Prop$ and for all objects $x$ of type $Nat$, $P(x) \subset P(x)$. How does it follow from here that the elements of this $A$ are functions? (And I think I also don't get why elements of $A$ contain $\lambda y$.)

Comment: @user1108335: Under the usual C-H isomorphism, $\lambda$ abstraction is analogous to making an assumption that you later discharge in a natural deduction proof. You could read $\lambda P: \mathrm{Nat{ \rightarrow \mathrm{Prop}. \lambda x:\mathrm{Nat}.\lambda y:P(x).y$ as the following *ordinary* proof: "Take a predicate $P$ and a natural number $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Assume that $P(x)$ holds. Then, by our assumption, $P(x)$ holds, which was to be shown." The term $p$ gives an explicit name to our assumption, $y$, so that we can refer to it unambiguously.

Comment: @user1108335
See the two tables in 1.11 (pp. 41, 44) https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/summerschool/summer14/rwh_notes/hott-book.pdf